# Change the style of the message box generated by withProgress()

Tags: r, shiny

The `withProgress()` function can generate a message box indicating the shiny app is running. But the message is at the top-right conner of the browser with a small text size, which makes the message not that eye-catching. So I wonder is there any way that I could change the style of this box, so that the message can be more expressive.

Answer (score 5):

You can alter the appearance (font, color etc) and position of the shiny progress bar with CSS (either [add it to your header or load css from a location on the server](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) (www folder)).

Also see: [this post from back when shiny was still new](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/VzGkfPqLWkY)...<del>I believe the `.shiny-progress` CSS class still applies.</del>  The CSS class changes to `.shiny-progress-container`.

Comment: I had to add the argument `withProgress(style = "old"...` for the custom CSS to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

On newer versions of Shiny, the progress bar shows on a *shiny notification* you can style modifying the following CSS class (by using `includeCSS()` or inside `ui.r` using something like `tags$head(tags$style(...)`):

```css
.shiny-notification{
  position: fixed;
  top: 33%;
  left: 33%;
  right: 33%;
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided a complete example, i.e., how to combine `tags$head(tags$style(...)` with the `.shiny-notification{}` code.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more details:
You can just include the HTML function tags$head() in the ui to overlay the progress bar. Since, as mentioned, it's a notification it can be called with .shiny-notification. Simplest way is to put this line somewhere in the ui and adjust the positions (and other CSS related parameters, [see here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(),

  tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-notification {position: fixed; top: 60% ;left: 50%)),

  sidebarPanel()
  mainPanel()
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite figure it out from the answers here, but a more complete answer provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694824/how-to-add-newline-in-the-detail-message-of-a-shiny-progress-bar) question got me there:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
      HTML(".shiny-notification {position:fixed;top: 30%;left: 0%;right: 0%;}"))),
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Launch long calculation")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    withProgress(message = "doing task 1",value = 0,{
      Sys.sleep(1.5)#task 1
      setProgress(0.3,message = "doing task 2",detail = "\n task 1 done")
      Sys.sleep(1.5)#task 2
      setProgress(0.6,message = "doing task 3",detail = "\n task 1 done \n task 2 done")
      Sys.sleep(1.5)#task 3
      setProgress(0.9,message = "Almost done",detail = "\n task 1 done \n task 2 done \n task 3 done")
      Sys.sleep(1.5)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```