# How to add Newline in the detail message of a Shiny Progress bar?

Tags: css, r, shiny

Is there any way to write add a newline character in a Shiny Progress bar message? `\n` or `<br>` does not seem to work.

I am trying to convert one of my old codes into a shiny app. The code basically calls a number of functions one after another, all of which take some time to execute. From the app, I would like to know which functions have already executed and the amount of time each of them took. I am trying to achieve this using the progress bar feature. Do let me know if there are better ways to do this.

Below is my dummy code. `\n`s are where I want to add a newline character. Let me know if what I am trying to do is not clear.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
      HTML(".shiny-notification {position:fixed;top: 30%;left: 0%;right: 0%;}"))),
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Launch long calculation")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    withProgress(message = "doing task 1",value = 0,{
      Sys.sleep(1.5)#task 1
      setProgress(0.3,message = "doing task 2",detail = "\n task 1 done")
      Sys.sleep(1.5)#task 2
      setProgress(0.6,message = "doing task 3",detail = "\n task 1 done \n task 2 done")
      Sys.sleep(1.5)#task 3
      setProgress(0.9,message = "Almost done",detail = "\n task 1 done \n task 2 done \n task 3 done")
      Sys.sleep(1.5)
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[This is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u88qM.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59995141/how-to-update-progress-bar-when-function-is-running-in-shiny-app