# How to update progress bar when function is running in Shiny App

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I'm new to shiny and I'm building some very basic demo app for a statistical model I built recently.

The app has a selectInput for some data tu run the model on, a *"Run Model"* button and a **observerEvent** depending on it. When clicking on it a dialog box appears with the message "Please wait...". However as te function is running there is no blue bar filling the box to show progress.

The function running the model is inside a **withProgress()**, I've tried putting a updateProgress() but I can't figure hoy to make the progress bar move as the model is running since the function is not inside a for loop.

If you wouldn´t mind to check the full repo out there, here is the link https://github.com/jgpeniche/Bayesian_T_TIIE.git

The code chunks in my app I'm referring to are the following:

Server

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

    observeEvent(input$run, {
        # wrap the loop execution in withProgress
        withProgress(

            message='Please wait',
            detail='Running Model...',
            value=0, {

                # Some code lines

                # Some function that takes really long time to run

                rnorm(1000000000, 0,1)
                updateProgress()
        })
})

})
```

Comment: For StackOverflow to work properly, you need to ask specific pin-pointed questions with examples that anyone can reproduce in a few commands. S.O. is not good at open-ended questions which take one all over the internet. KISS = Keep it simple...

Comment: Thanks @oaxcamatt, hope the edit addressed the KIS comment

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `incProgress()` to incrementally update the progress bar.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$run, {
    # wrap the loop execution in withProgress
    withProgress(

        message='Please wait',
        detail='Running Model...',
        value=0, {
            n <- 4
            # Some code lines

            # Some function that takes really long time to run

            rnorm(1000000000, 0,1)
            incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Finished section 1"))

            #more lines of code

            incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Finished section 2"))
    })
})

})
```